# Word adding extra spaces to the cells of tables copied from PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

When I copy a table from powerpoint into a word document template that my company has it is adding an extra space to every cell of the table is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. You must manually edit the Word table to suit your needs.